# Need Method Entry and Exit event in .net

Tags: aop

I like to have event like OnMethodEntry and OnMethodExit which will be used to raise an event when a method in a class is getting invoked in C#.NET.

I have seen Post Sharp which give this feature. Since it is third party tool, we like to design a library something similar to that.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Answer (score 1):

CodeProject has a nice article that I think will meet your needs: [MethodLogger - Hook into method calls in .NET binaries](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/methodlogger.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to modify assemblies by inserting these method calls manually in the IL.

Comment: Can you please give some idea about how to do this?

Comment: An easy way to accomplish this is to disassemble an IL assembly using `ildasm`, parse the resulting file to find all method entry and exit points and insert invocations of the events `OnMethodEntry` and `OnMethodExit` and then recompile using `ilasm`. There are more sophisticated ways but you'll need to take a deep dive into `System.Reflection.Emit` to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) or [CCI](http://cciast.codeplex.com/). They are good and mature libraries for reading and patching assemblies.